# How to view and edit files that were created and are used by my Android app?

Tags: java, android, json, file, storage

So I've created this simple app that asks the user questions (it's like a truth or dare game).
The questions are saved in a .json-file in SD-Card > Android > data > [package name] > files.

I want to make it possible, however, to add or delete those questions by manually editing or exchanging that .json-file in which the questions are saved (so that those new questions then appear in the app).

I already understand that the app needs to call the getExternalFilesDir() method somewhere, so that a directory that I can find in the device's file manager is created in the first place. However - as you probably have guessed - when I open that directory, the "files" folder is empty. (I know the .json-files must be in there since the app is working fine!)

Now my question:
Is there any way I can view and edit those .json-files? I don't care if the solution includes using a PC or some program.
Or should I maybe not save the questions in a .json-file but in a .txt-file instead? Or should I use a different directory to save my question files to begin with??

I would appreciate a detailed answer, since I'm obviously new.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I can include code on request.

EDIT: I don't want to edit those files from code, I already know how to do that. My question in particular is about whether there is a possibility to edit the json files using a text editor for example or exchanging the files using copy paste.

**Code:**

```
 public void copy() {
    Context Context = getApplicationContext();
    String DestinationFile = Context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + File.separator + "fragenAdvanced.json";
    
    if (!new File(DestinationFile).exists()) {
        try {
            CopyFromAssetsToStorage(Context, "fragenAdvanced.json", DestinationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void CopyFromAssetsToStorage(Context Context, String SourceFile, String DestinationFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream IS = Context.getAssets().open(SourceFile);
    OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(DestinationFile);
    CopyStream(IS, OS);
    OS.flush();
    OS.close();
    IS.close();
}
private void CopyStream(InputStream Input, OutputStream Output) throws IOException { //brauche ich das?
    byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
    int length = Input.read(buffer);
    while (length > 0) {
        Output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        length = Input.read(buffer);
    }
}
```

This is how I save the file to storage.

Comment: `Android > data > [package name] > files.` Come on! Are you a programmer? Did you mean: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files` ? Yes? Then it has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card.

Comment: I cannot believe that if you can save a file to getExternalFilesDir(null) that you cannot use it later if you again use getExternalFilesDir(null) as path to read the file. And every file manager app can show the content of that directory too. And then the user can open the file in the usual way.

Comment: @blackapps I do mean the directory on the external SDCard. It does not show the json files in the file manager

Comment: Please tell full path of that directory (like i did). Which Android version runs on used device? Which file manager app in use?

Comment: @blackapps /sdcard/Android/data/alex.com.wow/files/fragenAdvanced.json as mentioned above. I use Android 10. I first tried on the device manager that is pre-installed in Android. Then I tried "File Manager Plus" and I also connected the phone to my Windows PC and used it's explorer. You might know the "Device File Explorer" that comes with Android Studio. That is the only explorer, where I do see those json files. Any ideas why? (I copied the above path from there)

Comment: `/sdcard/Android/data/alex.com.wow/files/fragenAdvanced.json ` is the same path as `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/alex.com.wow/files/fragenAdvanced.json ` and has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. You have a removable micro sd card in your device? Then you can easily check that.

Comment: `P.S.: I can include code on request.` Please start with code that saves your file. Let it be clear which path you use.

Comment: @blackapps I appreciate your patience. I have now included code.
Also: thanks for the other explanation. I have a removable sd card in my device. I checked and the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/alex.com.wow/files` is empty, or rather the json files are not displayed. That's why I posed the questions

Comment: That looks ok. But i'm missing a Toast in the catch block for IOException. You need such to inform the user. And yourself. The used path is NOT on a removable sd card but on external memory fitted in your device. For historic reasons this is named sdcard. But you better look at the value of getExtenalFilesDirs(null).getAbsolutePath(). The `Files` app on your device will show this file.

Comment: @blackapps OMG, thanks!!! That explanation made it clearer, I found the files now! Have a nice day!

Comment: `Context Context = getApplicationContext();
    String DestinationFile =` Please adhere to the java convention to start variable names lowercase. Now your code is partly unreadable as all starting uppercase is a classname. Better: `Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String destinationFile =`.

Comment: @blackapps ok fine, will do.

Answer (score 0):

there is 3 way to save your user data but your way is not secure because the user has access on it.

- the first way is saving user data in SharedPreferences , it's very simple to use , but if user clears the app catch, the data will be deleted ( you can just convert your json to string and save it in sharedPreferences , for converting string to json you can use Gson library )
- second way is using SQlite and save data on local database , it will be deleted by clear stroge and still not good for important data
- the final way is using remote database and get data from api

Comment: Thank you, but you understood me wrong. I WANT the user to be able to have access on the files. My problem is that I - the user - cannot find and edit those files, when I would like to do so. Of course this way is not secure, but this is not my intention